# Why do I need an asterisk and some random variable in these Python Tkinter functions for them to work properly?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, arguments

In this basic Python Tkinter code, I'm trying to bind certain functions to trigger upon either a UI button press or a keyboard key press.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title('Test UI')

# Change text with "Enter" then flush
def changeTextEnter():
    text_label.configure(text=entry_bar.get())
    entry_bar.delete(0, tk.END)

# Close program key function
def quitApp():
    main_window.destroy()

# Enter Button
enter_button = ttk.Button(text='Enter', command=changeTextEnter)
enter_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Entry bar
entry_bar = ttk.Entry(width=30)
entry_bar.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Quit Button
quit_button = ttk.Button(text='Quit', command=main_window.destroy)
quit_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

# Text label
text_label = ttk.Label(text='TEST TEXT GOES HERE')
text_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

# Bind enter key
main_window.bind('<Return>', changeTextEnter)
# Bind quit key
main_window.bind('<Escape>', quitApp)

main_window.mainloop()
```

After a while of trial and error, it seems to work the way I want if I add an

```
*randomVariable
```

in the declarations of:

```
def changeTextEnter(*randomVariable):
```

and:

```
def quitApp(*randomVariable):
```

I get that one asterisk lets the function take an unknown number of arguments, and a double asterisk acts as a dictionary with key values.

My questions are:

1. Why do I need a parameter in those functions at all?
2. How does the variable "*randomVariable" get used, since it seems like I'm not actually using/ assigning anything to "randomVariable" anywhere within the function.
3. Why does the function not work as intended without the asterisk before the variable?

Comment: Put `print(randomVariable)` in your functions and you'll see what variable(s) are being passed to them.  I don't know Tkinter, but I'm guessing that when you `bind` a function it receives the key as an argument.  If a function is passed an argument it wasn't expecting, it raises `TypeError`.  You probably just want to add a single parameter (not a `*args` arbitrary-number-of-parmaters) called `_key` or whatever.

Comment: Callback for `bind()` expects an argument, the `Event` object. Whereas callback for `command` option of a `Button` object expects no argument.  Using `*randomVariable` fulfills both requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question and for providing a runnable code snippet!

#### Conclusion (TL;DR)

- You're using the same function to handle two different kinds of events (button push, keystroke).
- Because of this, your function has to handle different numbers of arguments
- Using `*` gives your function this kind of flexibility

#### About the `*` (asterisk)

You correctly mentioned that you can use `*` in a function's parameter list to accept any number of positional arguments. You probably have seen some function like this:

```
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

So now the question is "what is the difference between `*args` and `args`?" We can find the answer in the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists):

> An asterisk `*` denotes iterable unpacking. Its operand must be an iterable. The iterable is expanded into a sequence of items, which are included in the new tuple, list, or set, at the site of the unpacking.

The important word here is *unpacking*. Consider this example:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(my_list)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*my_list)
1 2 3
```

- `print(my_list)` just prints the list, nothing special here
- `print(*my_list)` actually does two things:

  1. *Unpack the list*
  2. Print the *elements* of the list one-by-one

In other words:

- `print(my_list)` is equivalent to `print([1, 2, 3])`
- `print(*my_list)` is equivalent to `print(1, 2, 3)` *<-- no square brackets*

#### Finding out why you need the `*` in your code

Here, I'll talk about the function `changeTextEnter()`, but the same applies to `quitApp()`.

Basically, you're using `changeTextEnter()` for two different things:

- For a Button command: `ttk.Button(..., command=changeTextEnter)`
- For a key binding: `main_window.bind(..., changeTextEnter)`

Pressing the "Enter" button and hitting the `<Return>` key both call `changeTextEnter()`, but **in a different way** (with different arguments).

You can use a debugger to observe this:

```
def changeTextEnter(*args):
    text_label.configure(text=entry_bar.get())  # <-- breakpoint here
    entry_bar.delete(0, tk.END)
```

Another way is to print the value of `args`:

```
def changeTextEnter(*args):

    # DEBUG
    print(args)

    text_label.configure(text=entry_bar.get())
    entry_bar.delete(0, tk.END)
```

| Action | Value of `args` |
| --- | --- |
| Pushing the "Enter" button | `()` (empty tuple) |
| Hitting the `<Return>` key | `(<KeyPress event ...>,)` |

You original code can't handle the second case because the function doesn't expect a positional argument:

```
TypeError: changeTextEnter() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

#### Side notes

- If you aren't interested in the `<KeyPress event>` object, you can change your function definition to this: `def changeTextEnter(*_)`. This will just "swallow" any positional arguments. The `_` name is a convention for "I don't care about this"
- One of the most prominent functions using `*` is the built-in [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function. Did you ever wonder how these calls work?:

  - `print()`
  - `print("Hello")`
  - `print("Cool number:", 42)`
  - `print("bla", "bla", end="")`

Have a look at the function definition, it uses `*`:

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`